# SMS and Call Windows Phone

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

There is any way to obtain the phone call duration and the amount of SMS sent during a specific period of time in windows phone 8.1(Windows Runtime) ?

For the data consumption i have found this `InternetConnectionProfile.GetNetworkUsageAsync` that gives me the data consumption, but for the SMS and the phone call i wasn't able to find anything.

to be clear i don't need to know the content of the SMS and the destination number of the phone call and SMS, i just need to read how many sms are sent during a day and how many minutes of call the user perform during a day

The last thing is that the app isn't going to the store.

**Edit**

i have found this for the calls but the phonecallhistory seams to be available only for windows 10 universal app: https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.calls.aspx

but still nothing for the SMS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting call logs (Which is what you need) is not currently possible.
There is no current API for reading SMSs either.
sorry

Answer (score 0):

The API is not available to Windows Phone or Windows Store apps